# Joining multiple tables using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

i am trying to join 3 tables using EF but it throws an error saying

```
consider swaping conditions on either side of equals
```

can some one pls help

```
 var billdata = from billtotal in context.billTotals
                                   join billcard in context.billClubcards
                                       on billtotal.OrderID equals billcard.OrderID

                                   join billtender in context.billTenders
                                       on billtender.OrderID equals billtotal.OrderID


                                   select billtotal;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The compiler error is quite correct:-

`The name 'billtender' is not in scope on the left side of 'equals'. Consider swapping the expressions on either side of 'equals'.`

The table you're joining from needs to be on the left, the one you're joining onto needs to be on the right. Hence:-

```
var billData =
    from billtotal in context.billTotals
    join billcard in context.billClubcards
        on billtotal.OrderId equals billcard.OrderId
    join billtender in context.billTenders
        on billtotal.OrderId equals billtender.OrderId
    select billtotal;
```

If you're wondering why, it's because the query syntax is just syntactic sugar for the underlying extension method:-

```
context.billTotals
  .Join(
    context.billClubcards,
    billtotal => billtotal.OrderId,
    billclubcard => billclubcard.OrderId,
    (billtotal, billclubcard) => billtotal)
  .Join(
    context.billTenders,
    billtotal => billtotal.OrderId,
    billtender => billtender.OrderId,
    (billtotal, billtender) => billtotal);
```

Your original implementation would expand to:-

```
context.billTotals
  .Join(
    context.billClubcards,
    billtotal => billtotal.OrderId,
    billclubcard => billclubcard.OrderId,
    (billtotal, billclubcard) => billtotal)
  .Join(
    context.billTenders,
    billtotal => billtender.OrderId, // billtender isn't in scope!
    billtender => billtotal.OrderId, // billtotal isn't in scope!
    (billtotal, billtender) => billtotal);
```

Answer (score 0):

The property of the table you are joining needs to be on the right side of equals

switch

from:      `on billtender.OrderID equals billtotal.OrderID`

to:      `on billtotal.OrderID equals billtender.OrderID`