# Can I apply join on four tables or anything similar in Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, join, asp.net-web-api

I have four tables

[image]
    Users
    {
    PK: UserId
    ...
    }

```
Products
{
PK: ProductId
FK: UserId
...
}

ProductTags
{
PK: ProductTagId
FK: ProductId
...
}

LikedProducts
{
PK: Id
UserId
ProductId
...
}
```

Here is my query.

```
int userId = 1; //It will be different for different user.
var tblProductList = (from t in repo.ProductTags
                                      join p in repo.Products on t.ProductId equals p.ProductId
                                      join u in repo.LikedProducts on p.UserId equals u.UserId
                                      join l in repo.LikedProducts on new { p.ProductId, userId } equals new { l.ProductId, l.UserId }
                                      where productIdList.Contains(p.ProductId)
                                      select p
                                       ).ToList();
```

I am getting The type of once reference in join clause is incorrect error.

I am getting list of **ProductId** let's say **productListIds** from azure search. My question is, Is it possible to get **some column(Not all data)** from each table using single query either by Join or using Entity Framework.

I googled It but didn't find any solution in which we could apply Join more than 3 tables.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: will this help ..?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13141862/joining-multiple-tables-using-entity-framework

Comment: I tried to but as you can see Product table is in center(productListIds) for other three table so not quite sure how to achieve the same.

Comment: please update your question with query you tried and what is obstructing you

Comment: `I tried to` - ok, could you provide what you have tried? Also define `some column(Not all data) from each table`, this really depends on what data you want and what the schema is. Based on that you execute either inner or outer joins.

Comment: I am not able to complete the query.

Comment: You have a userId passed in? Also define `some column(Not all data)`? What are you trying to extract? Just liked products or something else?

Comment: userId defines the user who requested for the products and form Users(UserName, FirstName, LastName), Products(Name, ImageUrl, TotalLikes), ProductTags(ListOfTags) and LikedProducts(isLikedByMe : If productId and UserId data exist than return true otherwise false).

Answer (score 0):

I am still unsure as to what you are trying to extract. Here is a corrected query though as you were using `LikedProducts` twice which is not necessary.

This would get a list of products that the user likes and products that have a tag (through the inner join):

```
var tblProductListOfLikedProductsForUser = (from p in repo.Products
    join tag in repo.ProductTags on p.ProductId equals tag.ProductId // as you are not retrieving tag info this is only usefull if you want to ensure that each product has a tag
    join l in repo.LikedProducts on new { p.ProductId, userId } equals new { l.ProductId, l.UserId } // limits products to those the user likes
    // join u in repo.Users on l.UserId equals u.UserId // no benifit in using Users if you dont want user info and already have a userid
    where productIdList.Contains(p.ProductId)
    select p).ToList();
```

---

> If productId and UserId data exist than return true otherwise false).

Here is a modified query that would return a list of product ids for those that the user likes and are in the list. The joins would only ensure that the product exists in all the tables (i have no idea what the referential integrity is of the db, if there are FK constraints defined you can get rid of the join on products).

```
var productIdsLikedProductsForUser = (from p in repo.Products // ensure the product exists
    join tag in repo.ProductTags on p.ProductId equals tag.ProductId // ensure the product has a tag
    join l in repo.LikedProducts on new { p.ProductId, userId } equals new { l.ProductId, l.UserId } // limits products to those the user likes
    where productIdList.Contains(l.ProductId)
    select l.ProductId).ToList();
```

If you do not care about that then you do not need a complex join, just query the `LikedProducts` table directly.

```
var productIdsLikedProductsForUser = (from l in repo.LikedProducts 
    where productIdList.Contains(l.ProductId)
    && l.UserId == userId
    select l.ProductId).ToList();
```

---

> As Products table contains UserId(FK reference of Users table) so Is it possible to include UserName, FirstName, LastName from Users Table?

Yes, you can use a [group by clause.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384063.aspx)

```
var userWithLikedProducts = (from l in repo.LikedProducts
    join u in repo.Users on l.UserId equals u.UserId
    where productIdList.Contains(l.ProductId)
    && l.UserId == userId
    group l.ProductId by new { u.UserName, u.FirstName, u.LastName }  into productGroup
    select new { User = productGroup.Key, LikedProductIds = productGroup.Select(x => x) }).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: As Products table contains UserId(FK reference of Users table) so Is it possible to include UserName, FirstName, LastName from Users Table?

Comment: @JyotishSingh - I added to the answer.

Comment: First of all thank you so much for you response however I need a single query through which we could get all the products form Products table based on "productListIds" which will include UserName, FirstName, LastName for user table(For each product). It also include all the tags form ProductTags table(One to many relation between Products and ProductTags) and If the user has liked certain products then the result will contains true otherwise false. Hope this will clear my requirement.

Comment: I have added database diagram as well.